# Programmatically get the current url of the page from where a Webform in a dialog has been loaded

Tags: 8, webforms, uri, modal-dialogs

The below link will open the webform (contact) in a dialog:

```
<a href="/form/contact" class="btn btn-success webform-dialog webform-dialog-normal">Contact</a>
```

this same link has been placed on many pages in my Drupal 8 website.

After the Webform is submitted, I want to know **the url of the page** from where the Webform has been loaded.

So say the above link is placed on the page of url: `/my-hobbies`, when a user will load the Webform from this page and submit it, I want to Programmatically know that the webform has been submitted from this url: `/my-hobbies`

In a CustomHandler, I have tried:

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t("This webform has been loaded from this url: $current_path"));
```

but the above code returned the path of the webform itself.

is this even possible in php ?

**UPDATE #1:**

The main idea behind knowing the current url of the page is because after the webform is submitted, i want to refresh the page from where the Webform is loaded and I am doing the refresh by redirecting the user to the same page url.

I am using below code to automatically close the Webform and redirect the user:

```
// Redirect the user using "Ajax Response".
// @See: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3002966
    $response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\RedirectCommand('/home'));
    $form_state->setResponse($response);
```

Comment: Possible, but unreliable. Check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable, and just bear in mind not to base any sensitive decisions on it, as it's trivial to spoof

Comment: Please check the update to my question, do you think this could lead to security issues ? any other method for achieving what I am asking for ?

Comment: Why do you need the URL at all if you're just refreshing the current page? Why not just `window.location.reload()` in a custom AJAX command? That way you'd sidestep any security issues

Comment: Why not just `window.location.reload()` in a custom AJAX command... Can you please provide an example on how I can implemented inside my CustomWebformHandler.php file ?

Comment: Here’s a full code sample: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2018-12-18/creating-custom-ajax-command-in